# How to rewrite outbound links in mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't find an answer to this looking at the beginners guide on the net. If someone could please help me out I'd be very thankful.

All I want to do is rewrite links (which exist in `<a href>` tags) on my page that look like this:

```
<a href="/mysite/products/product.cfm?id=1">/mysite/products/product.cfm?id=1</a>
```

into this:

```
<a href="/mysite/products/product/1">/mysite/products/product/1</a>
```

All the examples that I can find on the net are about inbound rewriting rules e.g. resolving a friendly-URL into a real URL.

But how do I turn a real URL into a fake URL on my page on the fly? I'm using Helicon Ape which is basically Apache mod_rewrite within IIS 7.5. I still have to put all my rules in .htaccess

If I use IIS URL Rewrite Module from Microsoft, then it allows you to create "Outbound" rules which rewrites links within your HTML markup on the fly. Here is an example of an Outbound rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to clean URL" preCondition="IsHTML">
<match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/article\.aspx\?id=([0-9]+)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="/article/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

So it rewrite any link in an `<a>` tag that looks like `/article.aspx?id=1` and makes it into `/article/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# externally redirect: /mysite/products/product.cfm?id=1 to /mysite/products/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(mysite/products)/product\.cfm\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internal forward: /mysite/products/1 to /mysite/products/product.cfm?id=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(mysite/products)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/product.cfm?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: But that will not rewrite the <a href> links on the page I don't think. It will only redirect if someone tries to access an ugly link.

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot go and change your HTML content, it can only change URL's when requests arrive at web server.

Comment: IIS Rewrite Module changes my HTML content. How else would I change all my links to user-friendly links?

Comment: Do you have documentation link for `IIS Rewrite Module changes my HTML content`. As far as I know mod_rewrite can only insert some static HTML into a page, it cannot alter HTML content.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Read the article. I think you misunderstood this outbound thing. IIS module is not changing the HTML content either. If you see screenshot you will notice `http://localhost/article.aspx?id=342&title=...` highlighted in red rectangle which is the original URL that will be rewritten to `http://localhost/article/342/some-article-title`

Comment: @anubhava you didn't read the article properly. The red boxes you mention are highlighting the problem. Continue reading *Create an outbound rewrite rule*. There is an image at the bottom with blue highlighting that shows this as being fixed.

Comment: @volumeone, you have to do it by yourself, by hand, changing the html of your links to "build" the new ones. mod_rewrite cannot do it automatically, and even if IIS Rewrite Module can "sort of" do so, you must have "obtained" somewhere the "pieces" that you want to take part of your new URL (in your `title`, etc).